# Core of multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $\phi$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose we have an operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by:

$$ D(T) = \{ f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; f\cdot \phi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \} $$

$$ (Tf)(x) = \phi(x)\cdot f(x) $$

**The question is to prove that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a core for $T$.**

Being a core means there exists a sequence $g_{n}$ in $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g_{n} \rightarrow f$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $Tg_{n} \rightarrow Tf$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

I can easily see this if we have a finite interval instead of $\mathbb{R}$ using density of $C_{c}^{\infty}$ in $L^{2}$ and DCT. This is what I tried.

Given $f \in D(T)$, There exists a sequence $g_{n}$ of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ functions such that $g_{n} \rightarrow f$ in $L^{2}$. Thus, there exists a subsequence $g_{n_{k}}$ such that $g_{n_{k}}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for almost all $x$. That means $\phi(x)\cdot g_{n_{k}}(x) \rightarrow \phi(x)\cdot f(x)$ for almost all $x$. However, now I am unable to use DCT as I do not have a bound for $\phi(x)\cdot g_{n_{k}}(x)$. This is where I am stuck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $D(T)=\{f\ |\ \int(|f|^2+|f\varphi|^2)dx<\infty\}=L^2(\mathbb R, (1+|\varphi|^2)dx)$.

Clearly $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^2([a,b], (1+|\varphi|^2)dx),$ for every finite interval $[a,b]$.

Applying DCT in $L^1(\mathbb R, (1+|\varphi|^2)dx)$ we see that the union of all  $L^2([a,b], (1+|\varphi|^2)dx)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R, (1+|\varphi|^2)dx).$

Comment: Could you explain a little more

Comment: which statement?